# How do I get the pixel coordinates for a specific bounding box

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I'm trying to get the pixel coordinates of the bounding boxes from the person class(labeled as:
mscoco_label_map.pbtxt

```
item {
  name: "/m/01g317"
  id: 1
  display_name: "person"
}
```

Currently I'm getting the bounding box and label onto the image via

```
input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
detections, predictions_dict, shapes = detect_fn(input_tensor)
label_id_offset = 1
image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np_with_detections,
          detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy(),
          (detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy() + label_id_offset).astype(int),
          detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy(),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          max_boxes_to_draw=3,
          min_score_thresh=.30,
          agnostic_mode=False)
```

(All code is inside while loop)

But when I print out detections['detection_boxes'] I get so many normalized coordinates and I don't know how to sort those coordinates to the specic box, eg. the person label.

So how can I get the pixel coordinates of a specific bounding box in detections['detection_boxes']?

New to StackOverflow, so any tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you want to convert from normalised coords to pixel coords?

Comment: Yes, specifically the coords of the person bounding boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `detection_boxes` should be an N by 4 array of bounding box co-ordinates in the form `[ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax]` in normalised co-ordinates, and `detection_classes` should be an array of (`float?) numeric class labels. I'm assuming they haven't changed the API much because I haven't used the object detection API since early last year.

You should be able to do something like this to convert to pixel co-ordinates and then get just on set of labels.

```py
detection_boxes = detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy()
detection_classes = detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy().astype(int) + label_id_offset
detection_scores = detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy()

# Scale to pixel co-ordinates
detection_boxes[:, (0, 2)] *= IMAGE_HEIGHT
detection_boxes[:, (1, 3)] *= IMAGE_WIDTH

# Select person boxes
cond = (detection_classes == PERSON_CLASS_ID) & (detection_scores >= SCORE_THRESH)
person_boxes = detection_boxes[cond, :]
person_boxes = np.round(person_boxes).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, but I still get like 20+ arrays even though there's clearly only one person box in the final preview window- any idea?

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot that I think it just returns all bounding boxes, so you need to also include a threshold on the scores. I've updated the answer.

Comment: One dumb question: what is person_boxes? Is it a nested array, because I get for ex. [[ 519  273 1489  738]] as result when I print it.

Comment: It's still a 2-D array of the same format as `detection_boxes`, just with fewer boxes.

Comment: and how do I access one of the four numbers in the 2D-array?

Comment: You can just index a column as you normally would, e.g. `person_boxes[:, 0]`.