# How to get pixel matrix values within the [0-255] range python

Tags: python, image, pixel, yolo, bounding-box

I did object detection for the image dataset and I saved the `bbox` coordinates for each detected object in this format:

```
(601, 1006, 604, 1009) #Xmin, Ymin, Xmax, Ymax.
```

I want to get the pixel values for each bounding boxes.

This is my code.

```
path = glob.glob(".../img_912.JPG")

for img in path:
    
     imgs = PIL.Image.open(img).convert('RGB')
     image_width, image_height = imgs.size
     imgArrays = np.array(imgs)
     X1 = int(df.iloc[0:, 1]*image_width)  #xmin
     Y1 = int(df.iloc[0:, 2]*image_height) #ymin
     X2 = int(df.iloc[0:, 3]*image_width)  #xmax
     Y2 = int(df.iloc[0:, 4]*image_height) #ymax
     cropped_image = imgArrays[X1:X2, Y1:Y2]
```

Comment: In general on a Series `s`, you should use `s.astype(int)` to cast it element-wise. Python's builtin `int()` function only works if the Series has only one element (scalar).

Comment: I got this error in cropped_image line: (TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method)

Comment: Yes, since X, Y, W and H are now Series of integers. If I get it right, you need to pick one value for each of your imgs. Maybe put that code outside the loop and `enumerate` over `path` to get the according index.

Comment: still same error: (TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method)

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to multiply by `image_width` or `image_height`.

Comment: why!. I need the pixel values for each bounding box. So, I got the pixel values for the whole image and then crop for each bounding box.

Comment: If you want to crop a rectangle 5px tall by 10px wide starting at top-left corner of image, you need `cropped =  imgArrays[0:5, 0:10]` surely? And the image height and width are not in there.

Comment: Does this solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/63954879/14290244